# UITableview cell Overlap on each with arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, arm64

hi i am trying to upgrade my app to support iOS arm64 after adding arm64
Tableview cells  Overlap on each (on iPhone 5s , 6 ,6+)

with arm64
[image: after adding arm64 tabelview cells is overlapped if i remove arm64 it run correctly]

Comment: Post your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` code

Comment: some one to help , plz

Comment: Can you post your project at anywhere?

Comment: ok it work now correctly by changing the return type of -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{} to be double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to precision from 32bit to 64bit.
Use Apple provided typedef primitive type, make all `int` to be `NSInteger` and float to `CGFloat`.

Pay attention that if you perform some calculation that should return a float number is really returning a float, if you divide 2 `int`s they will return an `int` not a `float`. In general if operands are of different types, the compiler will promote all to the largest or most precise type.

Answer (score 3):

You should change float to CGFloat for this method's output:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Now typing
if (indexPath.section >= [self.bubbleSection count])
{
    return MAX([UIBubbleTypingTableViewCell height], self.showAvatars ? 52 : 0);
}

// Header
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    return [UIBubbleHeaderTableViewCell height];
}

NSBubbleData *data = [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

return (CGFloat)MAX(data.insets.top + data.view.frame.size.height + data.insets.bottom, self.showAvatars ? 52 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. If you are reusing label or image then set it `Nil` before setting value for next row.

```
 rosterCell.imgContact.image = Nil; // rosterCell is custom tableview cell object
 rosterCell.lblContact.text = @"";
```

Another reason may be that you haven't set Autolayout constraint. It may help you